# How to redirect port to directory or subdomain with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, port, subdomain

How can I use .htaccess to redirect my directory: /panel or subdomain: panel.domain.com to port 8083?

For example, when someone visits panel.domain.com, it would be the same as visiting domain.com:8083.

I have tried  many .htaccess configurations but none seem to work in my scenario.

Heres my .htaccess file:

```
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /index.html /index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^panel.cdghost.xyz$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cdghost.xyz:8083/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^((?!builder/).*)$ https://www.cdghost.xyz/$1 [R,L]
ErrorDocument 400 /400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
ErrorDocument 504 /504.html
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8083$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ panel.domain.com/$1 [L,R=302]

#domain.com:8083 => panel.domain.com
#domain.com:8083/something => panel.domain.com/something
```

Or this for the other way around:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^panel.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain.com:8083/$1 [L,R=302]

#panel.domain.com => domain.com:8083
#panel.domain.com/something => domain.com:8083/something
```

Remember to have mod rewrite enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I am told "DNS lookup failed"

Comment: But the redirect did work? you enter to mysite.com:8083 and it redirected you to panel.mysite.com?

Comment: I think I described the problem wrong, I want panel.domain.com to be a 302 of port 8083 so when someone visits panel.domain.com, it is the same as visiting domain.com:8083.

Comment: If you want a 302 redirect, that's what I just did, domain.com:8083 302 redirect to panel.domain.com, if you want panel.comain.com to redirect 302 to domain.com:8083  let me know and I edit the answer with the rule.

Comment: Check it now. This is all tested and working in my server.

Comment: Its still not working, maybe a problem with my .htaccess file?

Comment: Please, explain "still not working" what message are you getting, 500 internal server error? Is it redirecting? It does nothing?

Comment: Its not reaching the server, just a DNS lookup failed message from chrome, if you wanna check its panel.cdghost.xyz

Comment: That's not htaccess problem have you setup your DNS properly for that subdomain?

Comment: I just did a ping to: panel.cdghost.xyz it's pointing nowhere, configure the subdomain to point to a server IP, it's not .htaccess problem My answer does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: It must be a problem with my dns, It should be set as a A record, but I just changed to a cname to test. Still not up though. Thanks anyways.

Comment: To test the htaccess, just edit your host file to make it point to the wanted IP address ;)